# Share node_modules between webparts

Tags: sharepoint, yeoman, web-parts, spfx

Here is my scenario:

- I have 7 different webparts
- In order to have more control over the projects I have split them in different projects
- All of the projects were created using the Yeoman installer

All was fine until I started to add them to the pipeline. Then I realize that I need to make `npm install` for every project. This is causing delay in my build pipeline as well as disk space.

My question is:

**How can different webpart solutions share single node_modules folder?**

Regards, Dimitar

Answer (score 0):

@JohnRambo,

A quick way is to create a Symbolic Link from a real `node_modules` folder to other projects.

```
mklink /d D:\shareablemodules\helloworld-webpart02\node_modules D:\shareablemodules\helloworld-webpart01\node_modules
```

More references:

- https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink

BR